# How to sort DataTable based on multiple column?

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable

I have `DataTable`

```
Name  Date
bbb   01/01/2011
bbb   01/01/2012
aaa   01/01/2010
aaa   01/01/2011
bbb   01/01/2013
aaa   01/01/2012
bbb   01/01/2010
ccc   01/01/2010
aaa   01/01/2013
ccc   01/01/2012
ccc   01/01/2011
```

I need sort this table sort by name and every name by date:

```
Name  Date
aaa   01/01/2010
aaa   01/01/2011
aaa   01/01/2012
aaa   01/01/2013
bbb   01/01/2010
bbb   01/01/2011
bbb   01/01/2012
bbb   01/01/2013
ccc   01/01/2010
ccc   01/01/2011
ccc   01/01/2012
```

How to sort DataTable in c#?

I've tried the following:

```
   DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
   dv.Sort = "col1 desc";
   DataTable sortedDT = dv.ToTable();
```

but this sort only by 1 column...

Comment: Might take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2777765/945456

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort.aspx

All you need to do is add a comma between the columns in the dv.Sort line.

To clarify

```
dv.Sort = "Name, Date";
```

Comment: OMG! Sorry... Do I need to delete this question? Or accept and forget?=)

Comment: @Bryuk: Is `Date` a `DateTime` or `String` column?

Comment: If it's string it doesn't work. Add these rows and look at the "suprising" sort: `dt.Rows.Add("Test", "01/01/2011");
            dt.Rows.Add("Test", "02/01/2010");`

Comment: I have to agree with @TimSchmelter here. If it's a string column you are much safer going the linq-to-dataset route where you can parse it to a date before doing the sort. That said, if the data you are currently dealing with happens to work with a simple string sort (i.e. you only ever have January 1st and are effectively sorting on year) then by all means take the easy solution. But please comment and unit test liberally.

Answer (score 4):

You can use LINQ to DataSet

```
var sortedDT = dt.AsEnumerable()
                 .OrderBy(r => r.Field<string>("Name"))
                 .ThenBy(r => r.Field<DateTime>("Date"))
                 .CopyToDataTable();
```

Use [CopyToDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to create new DataTable from ordered rows.

Comment: Thanks, but coma would be much easier=)

Comment: @Bryuk agree, in this particular case, when you have DataView, string-based sorting looks more simple. If later you will require more complex sorting, then take a look on [Sorting with DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669083(v=vs.110).aspx) article

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Linq-To-DataSet`:

```
var orderedRows = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                  orderby row.Field<string>("Name"), row.Field<DateTime>("Date")
                  select row; 
DataTable tblOrdered = orderedRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

If the `Date` column is actually a string column you need to parse it to `DateTime` first.

Assuming valid formats:

```
var orderedRows = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                  let date = DateTime.Parse(row.Field<string>("Date"), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                  orderby row.Field<string>("Name"), date 
                  select row;
```