# How to sort datatable and keep primary keys?

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable, primary-key

I have a datatable (dt) with 6 columns (S1, S2, S3 are `string` and D1, D2, D3 are `double`). The combination of the `string` columns (S1, S2, S3) make up my PrimaryKey:

```
dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] 
{ dt.Columns["S1"], dt.Columns["S2"], dt.Columns["S3"] };
```

Now, I want to sort dt by D1, D2, D3 and save it as a datatable.
Here is what I got:

```
DataView view = new DataView(dt);
view.Sort = "D1, D2, D3";
dt = view.ToTable();
```

The problem is dt is sorted the way I wanted by I lost my PrimaryKeys. I tried to replace the 3rd line with `dt = view.Table.Copy();` which keeps the PrimaryKeys but the sort won't work. I also tried using `LINQ` ([How to sort DataTable based on multiple column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204590/how-to-sort-datatable-based-on-multiple-column)) and checked this trend ([DataTable.DefaultView.Sort Doesn't Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208548/datatable-defaultview-sort-doesnt-sort)) but none of them worked.

Am I doing something wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to set the DefaultView.Sort property AFTER the view.Table.Copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every DataTable has a DefaultView property that allows you to set a Sort without creating a copy of your main table.

If you set the DefaultView.Sort property to your desidered sort order and then loop over the DefaultView instead of the DataTable you get your rows in the exact order required

```
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "D1, D2, D3";
foreach(DataRowView dr in dt.DefaultView)
   Console.WriteLine("D1=" + dr["D1"].ToString() + 
                   ", D2=" + dr["D2"].ToString() + 
                   ", D3=" + dr["D3"].ToString());
```

If you still want to create a new table then you need to recreate the primary key columns in the new table.....

```
//Get the primarykey column names
List<string> names = dt.PrimaryKey
                       .Cast<DataColumn>()
                       .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
                       .ToList();
// New table
DataTable dt2 = dt.Copy();
// Get the array of datacolumns that match the name of the other table primary
DataColumn[] keys = dt2.Columns
                       .Cast<DataColumn>()
                       .Where(x => names.Contains(x.ColumnName))
                       .ToArray();

// Set the primary in the copied table
dt2.PrimaryKey = keys;
```

Comment: Thank you Steve. Your code worked, but if I want to save this sorted version back in `dt` or even another datatable, should I loop over it?

Comment: If you assign the result back to the original dt variable you destroys it and create a new one. This of course is possible but as you have seen you loos the PrimaryKey set in the original table. However you could simply get the names of the columns in the primary key and rebuild it in the new table

Comment: Since I need to have the primary key columns, I will try your code (or check to see whether I can define the primary keys after the sort to avoid extra code). Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The shorter way is:

```
var brandNewTable = dw.ToTable();
```